# Stylus / Nib CSS with Node / Express secure app triggers Chrome warnings about insecure JavaScript

Tags: css, express, stylus

Console messages:

`The page at [...] ran insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand.`

and

`The page at [...] displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/quicksand/v2/sKd0EMYPAh5PYCRKSryvWz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff.`

and

`Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/quicksand/v2/sKd0EMYPAh5PYCRKSryvWz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff".`

I know what caused it--vaguely.  I just started implementing Stylus, Nib CSS modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Google research I found: http://mccormicky.com/1595/importing-google-web-fonts-lightspeed-web-store-ssl/

which makes it clear that the font requests should be switched to https for the whole thing to be considered secure, so then I looked into my /public/styles/style.styl file and found the offending line.   One extra `s` should be sufficient to clear the warning.  Indeed it's fine now.

It's really as simple as making the font request (found in the CSS styles file) over https instead of http.

I hadn't intended to be answering my own question (really thought the fix would be something complicated with the headers), but by the time I'd half finished it and done my due diligent research it was answerable.  So, whatever.